# function invoking undefined reference

Tags: c++, class, methods, undefined-reference

hi every one I have this class with those headers

```
class WuManber 
{
public:
WuManber( void );
virtual ~WuManber( void );

  void Initialize( const vector<const char *> &patterns, 
               bool bCaseSensitive = false, bool bIncludeSpecialCharacters = false, bool bIncludeExtendedAscii = false );
```

when I try try to create an instance of WuManber and invoke Initialize I get the following error:

> /tmp/ccx19Os5.o: In function `main': Test.cpp:(.text+0x8d): undefined
>
>   reference to`WuManber::WuManber()' Test.cpp:(.text+0xbc): undefined
>   reference to `WuManber::Initialize(std::vector<char const*,
>
>   std::allocator<char const*> > const&, bool, bool, bool)'
>
>   Test.cpp:(.text+0xc8): undefined reference to`WuManber::~WuManber()'
>   Test.cpp:(.text+0x115): undefined reference to `WuManber::~WuManber()'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

Parser CustomParserEx;
CustomParserEx.open("/home/abdullah/Project IDS/rules");

WuManber WmAlgorithm;
WmAlgorithm.Initialize(CustomParserEx.patterns,true,true,true);


}
```

so any hints of what I am doing wrong

Comment: Those are the linker errors. Are you compiling and linking the source files where the class WuManber member functions are implemented ?

Comment: ooohhhh thanks very much man I was indeed not including the source file WuManber.cpp how I didn't notice it .....!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't implement the three methods of WuManber, or you didn't include the implementations where the linker can find them.